# migrating data from one mongodb database to another with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, migration

I have to migrate about 19k accounts from one database to another, and change their formatting, etc. Wondering if anyone has a solid method for doing this, perhaps with a simple node.js script. I have searched for an example online, but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/kennethklee/mongoose-rolling-migration) come close?

Comment: That seems a little more complicated than I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply stream this with something simple like monk.js. Here's an example program (no shell here so it might not be 100% accurate):

```
var monk = require('monk');
var src = monk('localhost/my-database');
var dest = monk('remote-host/remote-database');

var users = src.get('users');
var remoteUsers = dest.get('newUsers');

users.find({}, { stream: true })
.each(function(user){

    // change some data
    user.profileImage = user.image;
    delete user.legacyPropery;
    user.name = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
    return user;
})
.error(function(err){})
.success(function(){});
```

That's the gist of it. Even if you have multiple related collections that you want to migrate as well (like, coments or stuff), streaming and moving one by one sounds like the best option. You can run like this in parallel (several processes or use this module in cluster module several times), you can count success/errors etc.

Almost the same as if you'd `mongodump` and then `mongorestore` on the new database, then run a converter script there. (with an $update or something.).

Comment: It will be a couple of days before I can give it a go. I'll mark this answer correct if it works out for me.

Comment: Although your answer led me in the right direction, I don't think it was close enough to what I did to actually mark this as correct. I ended up just doing a series of $unsets, $sets, etc to change the data to how I needed it, and then used Robomongo to copy the data to the new database. Worked great.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Didn't type it for points, anyway, just for help, and I'm glad if it helped a bit.
Though if I was fishing for points, I'd say that the answer is about as specific as I could make it, considering the level of details in the question ;)

Comment: You're right. Based on my actual question this answer is pretty awesome. I'll flag it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a npm package for this purpose. Using my package, you can give different sets of configurations and queries to move datas from one cluster/model into many cluster/models

configurations:

```
model:       // preferred model name
schema:      // Schema for the collection - reading the data
query:      // Query for searching over the collection
populate:   // Relation with other collections - Same with .populate() method
skip:       // skipping N values in the collection - same with .skip() method
sort:       // sorting - same with .sort() method
select:     // selecting keys - same with .select()
concurrent: // concurrent adjusts the pagination fetching constant
limit:      // total data will be fetched - same with .limit() method
```

example:

```
const MongooseTruck = require("mongoose-truck")
const conn1 = await MongooseTruck.connect("database_connection_string"),
    conn2 = await MongooseTruck.connect("database_connection_string"),
    conn3 = await MongooseTruck.connect("database_connection_string");
const parsedData = await MongooseTruck.create(conn1, [conn2, conn3]).loadFrom({
    model: 'People',
    schema: PeopleSchema,
    query: {
        name: "John"
    },
    populate: {
        path: 'stars'
    },
    skip: 0,
    sort: {
        _id: -1
    },
    select: "_id name surname age",
    concurrent: 20,
    limit: 100
}).emptyTo({
    model: 'People',
    schema: PeopleSchema
}).start({
    parse: true
})
```

GitHub: [mongoose-truck](https://github.com/cangokceaslan/mongoose-truck)

Npm: [mongoose-truck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-truck)